# Using Paperclip gem, how to modify style dimensions applied to an uploaded based on orientation?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, file-upload, paperclip

Working with the Paperclip gem and I want to change the dimensions for each style applied to an uploaded image differently depending on whether the image is in landscape or portrait orientation.

Basically something like this:

```
styles => {
:original => (uploaded_image.width > uploaded_image.height) ? "1000x800>" : :800x1000>",
:medium => (uploaded_image.width > uploaded_image.height) ? "600x400>" : :400x600>",
:thumb => "100x100#"
}
```

Is this possible?  And if so, how to make it happen?

Thanks

Comment: Don't know how, but that's a cool idea--if it's not already doable, I'll poke it with a stick and create a pull request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Didn't find a syntax as simple as the pseudo-code included in my original question, but I did find a fairly straight-forward way to do this.  Here's the code in my model.rb file:

```
  has_attached_file :cover_image,
                :path => "events/:created_at/event_:model_id/uploads/:basename_:style.:extension",
                :default_url => "placeholders/default_cover_image_:style.png",
                :styles => {
                    :original => Proc.new { |instance| instance.resize_cover_image('original') },
                    :iphone => Proc.new { |instance| instance.resize_cover_image('iphone') },
                    :thumb => "150x150#"
                }
```

and then this "resize_cover_image" method as such:

```
     # will resize each paperclip style and set orientation attribute when working on the :original style
  def resize_cover_image(style)
    geo = Paperclip::Geometry.from_file(cover_image.to_file(:original))

    case style
    when 'original'
      if geo.horizontal? 
        self.cover_image_orientation = 'landscape'
        "1360x910>"
      else
        self.cover_image_orientation = 'portrait'
        "910x1360>"
      end
    when 'iphone'
      geo.horizontal? ? "480x318>" : "318x480>"
    end
  end
```

If anyone has something better or any helpful comments on how to make this better ... I'm all ears.

Thanks -wg

Comment: FYI- I tried to do `:styles => Proce.new { ... }` and have it call a method that returned a hash of styles but it won't work (the proc is evaluated at the wrong time and in the wrong context).  You **HAVE** to use a separate proc for each style as @wgpubs posted above.

Comment: It looks like the to_file method no longer exists. Try using queued_for_write[style]